# Only receive GitHub email notifications when @mentioned directly

Tags: github

I am working on a medium-sized GitHub project (~10 active collaborators) and am getting flooded by tons of extraneous emails that I don't need to respond to. Ideally I'd only like to receive an email notification if someone directly @mentions me (in an issue, PR or elsewhere).

Currently this doesn't seem to be possible in GitHub's notification settings. Does anyone know of a way to "hack" this sort of functionality together (maybe using an email filter?)

Comment: I agree with your assessment that GitHub settings won't let you do this. An email filter will largely depend on the email client you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You can set GitHub to only notify you if you are directly mentioned.  In your profile settings, under **Notifications**, make sure the setting below is checked, and uncheck all of the other notification settings:

[image: Receive updates if you are mentioned]

That way you will only be notified when you are directly mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. Like much of github, obscure and unintuitive ...

Comment: This does not work for "only" mentions. As stated in the text, it includes all conversations you are participating in, which includes anything you've been asked to do a review for. This doesn't match with the question that asks for a notification when *only* @-mentioned.